# How to use IIF statement in view select statement

Tags: sql-server, view

I have the following SQL Server view select statement below, and I cannot get any results because it doesn't like = operator for some reason; I get an error:

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
> Unable to parse query text.

It won't let me save view query.

What I want is return modified select - is this even possible?  Right now this query will run if I take out the IIF.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.inventory.price, 
    dbo.product_price_multiplier.multiplier AS mult, 
    dbo.product_price_multiplier.item_number,  
    dbo.product_price_multiplier.width, 
    dbo.product_price_multiplier.length, 
    dbo.product_price_multiplier.width / 12 * dbo.product_price_multiplier.length / 12 AS units, 
    IIF (dbo.product_price_multiplier.length = 0.000, 
         dbo.inventory.price * dbo.product_price_multiplier.multiplier,
         (dbo.inventory.price * dbo.product_price_multiplier.multiplier) * (dbo.product_price_multiplier.width / 12 * dbo.product_price_multiplier.length / 12)) AS base_price
FROM     
    dbo.product_price_multiplier 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.inventory ON dbo.product_price_multiplier.item_number = dbo.inventory.item_number 
                  AND dbo.product_price_multiplier.length = dbo.inventory.length 
                  AND dbo.product_price_multiplier.width = dbo.inventory.width
```

Comment: "doesn't like"? Can you be more specific? Do you get an error message? What is it? Keep in mind we can't see your screen or the schema of the objects you're creating this view against.

Comment: FYI, 3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated. You should really be using aliases as use those to qualify your columns; your query would be far more succinct then too. Some good use of whitespace and line breaks would be great too.

Comment: `Error in list of function arguments` does not sound like a SQL Server error. Are you sure you are using SQL Server? What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` return? What tool are you using to create this view?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand it returns Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )

Comment: Ok, and what tool are you using, the view designer? Stop using it and create your view in a regular query window. The view designer is utter garbage and always has been. See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using the visual designers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers). Once you're using a proper UI then it will either accept your syntax or you'll get a real and meaningful error message from SQL Server.

Comment: The view designer

Comment: You should also consider updating your sql installation. You are on RTM, there are 16 cumulative updates released since sql 2019 went live.

Comment: Close the view designer and don't ever open it again. IMHO, anyway.

Comment: So my query looks OK?

Comment: Don't know, I can't really run it because I don't know your schema, and there are way too many table prefixes and parentheses and not enough carriage returns and indenting for me to try to spot-check it visually. What happens when _you_ try to run the query in a normal query window (and without bothering with `CREATE VIEW`)? Does it work? Do you get an error message? If you get an error message, what is it?

Comment: Yes it does - omg thanks allot

Comment: A few tips: don't use the designer a mentioned. Format your queries and views to make them readable. Use short table aliases to make them more readable. Don't use `RIGHT JOIN` as every right-join can be written as a left-join, and is more understandable. Be aware of integer division vs decimal division

Comment: Use CASE within a query to determine the return value of a column.  Use IIF to determine if a statement should be executed.  However, I strongly recommend against nesting queries within IIF statements.  Break your logic into conditional stored procedures and query stored procedures.  Conditional SPs use IIFs to determine which query SP to call.  This ensure whichever query ends up being needed will be optimized within a SP.  This also makes troubleshooting and logic/flow mapping easier.